# How do I access a "java" db2 local database via Ruby?

Tags: java, ruby

I have a java app which downloads from "the cloud" a local copy of a db2 database.  Then it accesses it using (I think) db2j.jar.  I know zero Java so I may be confusing matters.

One of the log files has:

```
Booting Cloudscape version IBM Corp. - DBMS:db2j - 5.1.2
```

and then the path to the local copy of the database.

The local database is a directory.  Some of the files in it look like seg0/c10.dat, etc.

My question is how do I open this database (connect to this database) from Ruby 1.9?  Where and how do I specify the path to the database?

I see lots about connecting to a remote db2 server but nothing about this particular style of db2 database.

Comment: You can call java methods using Ruby (http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=214719)  so I would check out the Cloudspace API info (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wsadhelp/v5r1m2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.etools.rsc.doc%2Ftopics%2Ftdbconn_cloudscape.html)

Comment: Thanks. I almost added it to the question.  I'm using MRI.  I don't even have java installed on my laptop (Mac).  So, the JRuby option isn't open to me.

Comment: Newer versions of Cloudscape can, I believe, be accessed the IBM Data Server Client, but I believe that wasn't available until Cloudscape 10.